# Can't get deployd pdf modul to work dpd-pdf

Tags: node.js, pdf, deployd

i have install'ed deployd pdf modul dpd-pdf
https://github.com/diadistis/dpd-pdf

In dashboard i creted a /pdf  with conf path to

```
C:\export\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe
```

"wkhtmltopdf path"

but when i post to http://localhost:2404/pdf
i just get this return, and no pdf files anywhere

```
    {
    "message": "resource not found",
    "status": 404
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got same error..

solve it, if you are on windows make sure to run as admin

and make sure that the body of the request is sent as application/json or application/x-www-form-urlencoded.